# C# Split string in elegant way

Tags: c#, split

I can have two cases of the string line.

```
string mystring =  "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee"
```

and

```
string mystring2 = "aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eeee/";
```

Of course I can use a split by '/' and do some checks, but I am looking for some elegant solution.

if i do mystring.Split('/') it can be on 2nd or 3rd position in array, how do I know where it is?

How do I get 'ccc' ?

THanks!

Comment: Please elaborate on why you're not just using mystring.Split('/');

Comment: what is wrong with `string.split()` ?

Comment: if i do mystring.Split('/') it can be on 2nd or 3rd position in array, how do I know where it is?

Comment: Why do you need to split and what do you need to check for?

Comment: Why is `String.Split(new Char [] {'/'})` not "elegant" enough?

Comment: So you want to get `ccc` - what rules define its location?

Comment: you can try int idx = mystring2.IndexOf("/ccc/");

Comment: dear mr goat.. what exactly will be on "2nd or 3rd position" in the array? if you want to get a specific text on your string, you shouldn't be splitting, you should use `string.Substring' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)

Comment: He means that because of the leading slash, there will be an empty entry in the array, this is solved using StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries as pointed out in Scroog1 's answer +1

Comment: Hey, it's a rather poorly formed question, but he clearly stated what he wants. He wants to find the third segment while ignoring the leading and trailing slashes. Derekaug already figured that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
string mystring =  "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee";
string mystring2 = "aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eeee/"; 

string[] result = mystring.Trim({'/'}).Split('/');
string[] result2 = mystring2.Trim({'/'}).Split('/');
```

Then, `result` and `result2` would be the same.

Comment: With this solution and a string like `"aaa//bbb"`, the `"bbb"` portion would not be in the same location as for `"aaa/bbb"`; with Joe's solution, it would be.

Comment: yeah, i actually upvoted Joe's solution. Was not aware of `StringSplitOptions`.

Answer (score 7):

You're question isn't very clear, but I'll take a stab in the dark and assume you want to ignore the empty entries which result from a slash at the start and end of the input string.

In which case you could try:

```
String.Split(new string[] {"/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: By my intepretation of OP's question, this seems to be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
myString.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ElementAt(2);
```

Comment: Why use ".ElementAt" when you could just use `myString.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2];`?

Comment: I had obviously been playing with too many things that returned IEnumerable that day.

Answer (score 0):

What is more elegant than the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method? It takes the delimiter and spits out an array of the split string.

Comment: if i do mystring.Split('/') it can be on 2nd or 3rd position in array, how do I know where it is?

Answer (score 0):

Elegant or not, you can still use `Split` and check for the condition that seems to be the problem: does it start with a slash or not?

```
string[] split = mystring.Split("/");
if (mystring.StartsWith("/"))
    // index = 3;
else
    // index = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the length of the result and only return the results that is relevant.

```
var split = mystring.Split('/').Where(p => p.Length > 0).ToArray();
var split2 = mystring2.Split('/').Where(p => p.Length > 0).ToArray();
```

This would generate identical results for both strings.

Then if you need to figure out the position in the Array, you can simply do the following.

```
int position = Array.IndexOf(split, "ccc"); // Returns 2
int position2 = Array.IndexOf(split2, "ccc"); // Returns 2
```

Finally to confirm that you got the correct position/index you could do something like this:

```
string string1 = split[position];
string string2 = split2[position2];
```